# Socket.io connection status acknowledge

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I am using socket.io to build a single player/multiplayer application.
Client side:

```
let socket = io(host,{autoConnect: false,forceNew: true});
```

Whenever the user press on the multiplayer option, I start connection to the server as

```
socket.connect();

if(socket.connected) console.log("Success")
else{
   showToast(0,"Connection Issue","Failed to connect to server")
   socket.disconnect(); 
}
```

The problem is **socket.connected** doesn't wait for the response of **socket.connect()** and always evaluate as false.
How to wait for the response of socket.io connection request?

I tried below events but none was fired.

1. socket.on("connect",()=>alert("Connected"));
2. socket.on("disconnect",()=>alert("Disconnected"));
3. socket.on("connect_error",()=>alert("Connection Error"));

Comment: If you remove the if and register the event before calling `socket.connect` will connect event fired?

Comment: @kennarddh kindly clarify more.

Comment: Register `connect`, `disconnect`, `connect_error` after that call `socket.connect()` and remove the if after `socket.connect`. What output is logged?

Answer (score 2):

Here, I used the connect method in my previous project to get the connection event. It's working fine.

```
socket.on("connect",()=>alert("Connect"));
```

You also verify this method from the socket.io official website:
https://socket.io/docs/v4/client-socket-instance/

In this case, You also need to cross-check with the server side got any connection or not. Maybe some issue with the connection between the client and server.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [@kennarddh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14813577/kennarddh)

```
socket.connect();
socket.on("connect",()=>alert("Connected"));
socket.on("disconnect",()=>alert("Disconnected"));
socket.on("connect_error",()=>alert("Connection Error"));
```

Appreantly using socket.connected doesn't wait for the reponse. registering event using socket.on to be called on the status of the request worked!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).